# How to select whole entries based on 'SELECT DISTINCT' SQL command in pypmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in the phpmyadmin server containing 17700 entries, but there are duplicate values in one column (columnA). The following command confirms this and tells me that there 17231 unique values in columnA:

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnA FROM Table;
```

But this only prints columnA, whereas I want to get all the data for every entry (i.e. the whole row in the table) which has a value in columnA that only appears once in the dataset. When I've searched for an SQL command that does this I keep returning the one above so I think that I may need a version of this command which is specific to phpmyadmin or MYSQL?

Similarly I would like to see the whole data set (i.e. the whole row) for each entry with a value in columnA that appears MORE than once. I have a command that lists the values that appear more than once in columnA:

```
SELECT columnA FROM Table GROUP BY columnA HAVING count(*) >1;
```

But again this only prints columnA and I need to see the whole row for every entry that has a value in columnA which appears more than once.

Any suggestions? 
​

Comment: what if you use `DISTINCT` for all the columns you are trying to fetch?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where id in (select id from table group by columnA having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to list the columns you want to see. Use can use "*" to refer to all columns, which may be okay depending on how you are using it, but generally it's best to list the specific columns you want, in the order you want it. Example:

For your first question:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC FROM Table GROUP BY columnA HAVING count(columnA) = 1;
```

and for your second question:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC FROM Table, 
(SELECT columnA FROM Table GROUP BY columnA HAVING count(columnA) > 0) AS Table2
WHERE Table.columnA = Table2.columnA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select Top 1  with Ties *
      From table
      Order by row_number() over (partition by columnA order by [field] desc))
```